# cart total only calculating for the first 2 products only in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 2 types of products in my app.Products with attribute and products without attribute. I can successfully add the products to cart, but I am having an issue whereby on the part of showing the grand total,only the total of the first 2 products subtotal are calculated and shown.I haven't understood where the bug is. I have tried debugging the code but still can't figure it out. Here is the HTML code that process the grand total price.

```
          //table that shows the cart details and where the subtotal is calculated
<table class="userdatatable table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%; border:2px solid black;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <body>
        <?php $total_price=0; ?>
        <?php $attributetotal_price=0; ?>
        <?php $noattributetotal_price=0; ?>
        @foreach($cartitems as $item)
            <tr>
                @if ($item->product->is_attribute==1)
                    <?php $attrpric=Merchadise::getdiscountedattrprice($item['product_id'],$item['size']);
                        
                    ?>,
                @else
                    <?php $discountedprice=Merchadise::getdiscountedprice($item['product_id']);
                                
                    ?>
                @endif
                <td>{{ $item->product->merch_name }}</td>
                @if ($item->product->is_attribute==1)
                    <td>{{ $attrpric['merch_price'] }}</td>
                @else
                    <td>{{ $item->product->merch_price }}</td>
                @endif
                
                <td>
                    <img src="{{ asset ('images/productimages/small/'.$item->product->merch_image) }}" style="width:100px; height:100px;" alt="Product">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="itemupdate qtyminus" type="button" data-cartid="{{ $item->id }}">
                        <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                    <input data-id={{ $item->id }} class="quantity" min="1" name="quantity[]" value="{{ $item->quantity }}" type="number">
                    <button class="itemupdate qtyplus" type="button" data-cartid="{{ $item->id }}">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
                @if ($item->product->is_attribute==1)
                    <td>sh.{{ $attrpric['discount'] * $item['quantity'] }}</td>
                    <td>sh.{{ $attrpric['final_price'] * $item['quantity'] }}</td>
                @elseif($item->product->is_attribute==0)
                    
                    <td>{{ ($item->product->merch_price-$discountedprice) * $item['quantity'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $discountedprice * $item['quantity'] }}</td>
                @endif
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="confirm return('Are you Sure You want to Delete?')" href="{{ route('deletecartitem', $item->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
                {{-- show cart total --}}
            @if ($item->product->is_attribute==1)
                <?php $attributetotal_price=$total_price+($attrpric['final_price'] * $item['quantity'] );
                ?>
            @elseif($item->product->is_attribute==0)
                <?php $noattributetotal_price=$total_price+($discountedprice * $item['quantity'] );?>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 ml-auto">
        <div class="cart-page-total">
            <h2>Cart totals</h2>
            <ul class="mb-20">
                <li>Coupon Discount
                    <span class="couponAmount">
                        @if (Session::has('couponAmount'))
                        -Sh.{{ Session::get('couponAmount') }}
                        @else
                        sh.0   
                        @endif
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li>Grand Total 
                    <span class="grand_total">Sh.{{ $attributetotal_price+$noattributetotal_price-Session::get('couponAmount') }}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            @auth
                <a href="{{ url('checkout') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Checkout <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            @else
                <p>To proceed to checkout create or log in to your account...</p>
                <span href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RegistrationModal" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Create/Login an Account<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
            @endauth
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my products migration table
[image: first part of the migration]
[image: second part of the migration]

Comment: can you share your `products` table migration data

Comment: change all  your if condition `$item->product->is_attribute==1` to `$item->product->is_attribute == "1"`, make `1` to `"1"` also `0` to `"0"`

Comment: still the same error appears

Answer (score 0):

it was just a minor bug.i removed the $total_price

```
  {{-- show cart total --}}
@if ($item->product->is_attribute==1)
  <?php $attributetotal_price=$attributetotal_price+($attrpric['final_price'] * $item['quantity'] );
            ?>
@elseif($item->product->is_attribute==0)
 <?php $noattributetotal_price=$noattributetotal_price+($discountedprice * $item['quantity'] );?>
@endif
```